# Express in Google Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

Watching some tutorials on firebase cloud functions it seems like express is pretty much the standard tool. I was wondering though if it would make any sense to pull up a separate express app for each function so that each mini-app contains only a single route. Or should I create one function, which is an express app managing all the request handlers?

The convenience of the first approach is that I can see separate logs for each function in the console.

The advantage of the second one is that I can use dynamic urls, and match on parameters. Like `"user/1234/cars"`. (I'm not planning to do so)

What I would be really interested in is which one is more resource efficient or faster, how often are these function environments re-created?

If each function call uses a separate environment, I assume the first approach is better, since the footprint of the app is smaller. If it's not the case, I assume the latter one is better.

Answer (score 1):

With serverless backends, like Cloud Functions, you generally don't worry about scaling.  It will happen automatically in response to the load on your endpoints, and you don't have any control over how that happens.  The scaling behavior is an implementation detail of the system, and the system gets to decide what's best.

The only thing that you, as the application developer, need to worry about is writing and deploying the code that works the way that suits you the best.  You need not thing about sacrificing convenience of features in order to scale better (because, as mentioned, you can't control the scaling behavior anyway).

If you want more sophisticated and configurable logging, look into using StackDriver instead of the console logs.